# How to ban a user permanently from using my website?

Tags: php, cookies

I am trying to block a user's PC permanently from using my website. Until now what I did is banning the IP address and setting a cookie which will automatically ban the IP address, if it changes. However some tricky users are nevertheless deleting the cookie and resetting their router, so they can write harmful comments on my website. Is there any other way of banning a user, other than with IP ban and cookies?
I read this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159160/how-to-definitively-ban-a-user-from-my-website-or-almost but it is not what I am looking for.

Comment: People can still go to internet cafes or to their neighbour's PC. No protection will prevent this.

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference is between your question and the link you've supplied.

Comment: I think the question could be rewritten - as I understand it, the OP wants to ban a user from posting comments, whereas the other question is about banning them entirely.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [evercookie](http://samy.pl/evercookie/), which is a lot harder to get rid of, but identifying individual PCs with certainty is not really possible, and that's a *very good thing* because it would be the end of privacy.

Comment: Good Idea, but would it be useless if the user used different browser/incognity/private browsing?

Comment: @ricky: maybe, maybe not, but there's no better alternative.

Comment: Depends on the browser, evercookie would be pretty useless against TOR, but some dumber private-mode browsers *cough cough* Internet Explorer *ahem* might not fully delete the cookies.

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't. Any method you put in place can be worked around. You can identify a previous user by:

- IP address - which changes automatically, and can be changed manually with something like Tor
- Cookie - which can be deleted easily, as you said above
- Login details - which would require you to block commenting for non-registered users, and blocked users could register with new details anyway. You could require pre-approving accounts.

Note that this is a very difficult thing to do. Even the biggest sites struggle with this - StackOverflow included. Ultimately, it's a trade-off between making it easy for good users and difficult for unwanted users - you, as the site owner, has to decide where the optimal experience lies.

One other option is to pay for comments moderation with something like Mechanical Turk or Freelancer.com.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, 100% authentication is impossible, aside from anything else someone could just go to an internet cafe or use a friends computer. But you could try making a few changes to your site if you have a big problem with this:

- You could make users sign up to post, and even go so far as have new users comments not show up until they are approved, either by yourself or other trusted users.
- You could try hellbanning, which means you flag a user as hellbanned, they can still log in and post etc. but their comments only show up for them no one else.
- You could try automatically scanning posts for certain offensive terms (or whatever is relevant in this case) and then automatically delete or hold them until approved manually.

Spam intentional or otherwise is a tricky problem and anyone who completely solves it will likely become very rich.

Comment: Wow, I like the hellbanning method, nice!

Comment: Hellban is a very good idea that I'd never heard of before. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/06/suspension-ban-or-hellban.html

Comment: I know what you mean, it is just so subtle yet marvellously evil.

Comment: If auto-scanning posts for offensive terms, ensure you've read up on the Scunthorpe problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem

Answer (score 2):

One idea, often seen in phpBB like systems, is a role approach.  You assign different abilities to guest or visitor users, from registered users, from trusted registered users.  A basic scheme for it would be like this.

- Guest

  1. Requires CAPTCHA
  2. Requires moderator approval
- Registered users

  1. Requires moderator approval
- Trusted Registered Users

  1. Can freely post comments

Your CMS affects the way this would be set up.  The simplest (assuming it doesn't already support this) would be storing a few extra bits in the database indicating the role and checking that when posting.

Answer (score 1):

Just get bastard's region with GEOIP functions and set some restriction for this region (for example premoderation/captcha/etc).

Also You can use "protection" from another services, which is more powerful. For example: connect Your site accounts with facebook acc and allow to comment only after getting facebook_id. It's pretty easy to ban user by facebook_id and hard+slow for bastard to create accounts for every Your ban ;)

Comment: Your first idea is terrible, imagine if you unwittingly banned 8.5 million people because one person in NYC posted spam.

Comment: @RobertMoore 5 years since the answer, I was young and expressive :) Anyway it's still the best option to use any social network to identify user and then ban him/her. Banning a region is pretty fun (If you understand what I mean), but it's like to shoot a cannon on sparrows, yeah