# How to ban users from my Django app (with a twist)

Tags: python, django, proxy, ip

I have a web-based Django app where users congregate and chat with one another, under pseudonyms.

Most of the users hitting this website do so via **Opera Mini**. Unlike straightforward web browsers, Opera Mini has a **twist** that it fetches all content through [a proxy server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_Mini#/media/File:Opera_mini.png), and reformats web pages into a format more suitable for small screens.

I want to implement a banning feature in this app. Some users are terrorizing others - if I manually ban them right now, they simply return under new nicknames. Note that these users aren't very tech savvy - almost all are not more than semi-educated. My question is thus-pronged:

1. Is banning user IP effective when they're using proxy such as Opera Mini?
2. Is there any reputable Django plugin available that handles IP blocking elegantly?
3. If 1 doesn't hold (in which case, 2 won't either), is there any other robust method I can follow to keep out antagonistic users and protect my community?

Currently, I've given these users a "downvote" feature, muting accounts whose posts receive too many downvotes. But that is of virtually no help in **flame-wars**. The abuser keeps returning under new pseudonyms, undermining the whole community. Maybe I should try [hellbanning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9113541/4936905), if nothing else works?

*Note: I'm not an advanced programmer (more of a designer), so I'll prefer swift solutions that have a small time-to-market for someone like me.*

Comment: Related discussion on hellbans: http://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/393/78

Comment: sounds like an interesting community

Comment: Andy - thanks for the link! Chris - the community's mostly formed of people who've newly begun experiencing the Internet. They primarily come from villages or city out-skirts, and have recently procured their first ever computing devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this section of the Opera Mini documentation](https://dev.opera.com/articles/opera-mini-request-headers/). The Opera servers will be sending you an `X-Forwarded-For` header which contains the original IP of the client, which you can access in Django with `request.META['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']`.

That said, some things to bear in mind (I live and build websites in a country where Opera Mini has largest web browser market share):

- It sounds like many of your users are connecting from phones. This means that they are highly likely to have dynamic IP addresses. Their IP can change frequently and if you ban one IP now it may end up blocking access for a different user a few minutes/hours later. If you do ban IPs, then it is advisable to set a fairly short timeout.
- `X-Forwarded-For` headers are notoriously unreliable. They will often contain internal IPs and you need to filter those out. There is also no guarantee that you will get the correct upstream IP (consider cases where the user is behind a VPN/Tor node/etc). You also need to account for any reverse proxies that you may have in front of your application.
- People who really want to abuse the system will find a way in. A moderation and/or reputation based system is the only way to keep their noise to a minimum.

Comment: solarissmoke: do you have any experience vis-a-vis meaining IP block lists for feature phone users? If I do implement an IP ban, I'm trying to ascertain how long it should last (10 mins? 60 mins?). This is a subjective question, I suppose if you've had experience in the domain, you could give some data points on it.

Comment: It really depends on the network operators and how frequently they reassign IPs (which I guess is a function of the size of their IP pool and the number of clients), so hard to give any sensible numbers. I think realistically you need to use IPs as one signal in your heuristic, but should not rely on IP only otherwise you will almost certainly block someone who doesn't deserve to be blocked.