# A big and ever-growing table in my Django app needs a better performance strategy

Tags: python, django, performance, postgresql

For first-time Internet users from developing economies with very basic, non-js supporting mobile phone devices and flaky Internet coverage, I host a simple Django-based message board.

The "home" page of this message board is the main gig. It's where everyone can just directly write anything. Moreover, users constantly refresh this page to see if anything new has appeared from other users (it's read heavy); treating the place as a public chat room.

This home page is fed by a table that is big (>1M rows) and ever-growing (>10K added every day; accelerating). It's represented by a class-based ListView in **views.py**. I happen to need only the **latest ~200 rows** from this big table (ordered by `'-id'`), since my users don't dig into the past. Thus in the CBV, `queryset = Post.objects.order_by('-id').exclude(submitter_id__in=condemned)[:200]` (`condemned` are users who are [hell-banned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33573743/how-to-ban-users-from-my-django-app-with-a-twist), `submitter` is a `User` foreignkey). Moreover, there is a whole bunch of additional stuff happening in `get_context_data()`.

According to new-relic, this CBV is by far the most time-consuming view I have in my app. Running `SELECT` on the big table takes by far the most time. I can't cache the home page because users are treating this message board as quasi-chat.

Could I have framed that queryset slice differently, or that's the best I can do? From your experience, does anything jump out that you think I ought to do to improve the performance of this CBV? I'm open to sharing more information, so ask away if needed. My db is postgresql.

Comment: You mean to say something like: `Post.objects.exclude(submitter_id__in=condemned)[200:]`?

Comment: Allow me to ask a noob question Sayse. Can you clarify what you mean by "presuming you haven't changed it from `id` in the meta". I've seen a reference to this in a ton of places, but I haven't been able to lock down what precisely this means.

Comment: I've moved my comments into an answer to free up space under your question, I'll delete my other comment soon too.

Comment: Oh like that. Well I haven't explicitly defined the Meta for any of my models, so it should certainly be ordered by id. BTW when I peek into actual records of this table in postgresql, I don't see the actual enteries physically ordered by id. Should they be, or is that unrelated?

Comment: I think that might be unrelated, it probably depends on how postgres chooses to display its records. Also, I'm not sure if django does this first anyway but have you tried excluding before ordering? (If you do decide you need to order_by)

Comment: I haven't. I think I'll try that and get back to you. Thanks a ton for helping out :-)

Comment: No worries, make sure to use the `connection` class or django debug toolbar to see exactly what query(s) is being ran

Comment: Yea, I have the debug toolbar, that's what I'm using to profile this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Moved my comments into an answer</sub>

I would imagine that the thing that is taking the longest time is the ordering.

From the docs for `order_by`:

> Ordering is not a free operation. Each field you add to the ordering incurs a cost to your database.

Judging by your query, you don't really need to order_by at all and can just take from the opposite end like you have done in your comment

```
Post.objects.exclude(submitter_id__in=condemned)[200:]
```

This would work as by default, a models `ordering` which order_by uses from the models Meta class is `id`.

The only other thing that may be making a difference depends on what `condemned` is, I'm hoping its a queryset too but if it isn't (i.e some read in text file) I would look into that also.

Since you have said that condemned is a list derived from `values_list`.

`values_list` might not help I don't think because I think it resolves the query, You might want to try with either `.all` or just `.values('id')`. Values returns a `ValuesQuerySet` which if im not mistaken doesn't resolve the query. I haven't looked into what values_list returns though

Edit: I've just looked and `values_list` returns a `ValuesListQuerySet`, and obviously a dictionary lookup (which `values` uses) would be faster than a list lookup

Comment: condemned is a list of user `ids` essentially. I.e. it is `HellBanList.objects.values_list('condemned_id',flat=True)`, where this particular `condmened` is a foreign key on `User`.

Comment: Got it, feel free to move this bit into the answer too.

Comment: @HassanBaig - Done it, also just looked up what `values_list` returns which may interest you

Comment: Just to update: doing `[200:]` over a data sample is returning an *empty* queryset. I'm figuring out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @HassanBaig - hmm I just tried it with `[1,2,3][200:]` and that returns an empty so that must be pythons go-to if there aren't 200 elements.. it may not be possible.. Edit: Oh of course, its `[start:end]` so that won't work

Comment: @HassanBaig - You could try `.exclude().reverse()[:200]` but I think that might be the same as ordering by `-id` anyway

Comment: Maybe I should create an *archive model* that's inherited from the existing `Post` model, and write a job to transfer older records from `Post` to `PostArchive` every few hrs?

Comment: @HassanBaig - You could try but I'm not sure what difference it would make, you could also try filtering down by the last day or something so theres less to order, definitely make condemned use values though

Answer (score 0):

You need to create index on submitter_id field of PostgreSQL.
Also if you want to users to see messages instantly you can use Meteor DDP for django, in short words it will expose objects collections via Distributed Data Protocol and then in a front-end MeteorJS will catch changes and show new messages without need to reload (it uses sockets). Just try my app I wrote at ioaware.meteor.com, I created it in 2 days, just register and add a lesson, and look for this process in separate browser

Comment: Quick question: if I set "db_index=True" for submitter_id attribute of the relevant model, would I need to run syncdb again?

Comment: I would love to use Meteor DDP - but unfortunately vast majority of my users have devices that don't support JS. Meteor DDP would work with a JS front-end, would it?

Comment: Meteor need javascript.

Comment: You dont need to change orm model, or syncdb, but you need to call to postgresql shell directly. on linux psql - U <username> -d <db_name> and then you type CREATE INDEX appname _modelname_fieldname_id ON appname_modelname

Comment: Okay so I need to do it manually. But another thing: `submitter` is a foreign key on `User`, hence won't submitter be indexed automatically anyway?

Comment: @DmitryYudin - Calling a command in a postgresql shell directly is a *very* bad idea, if you ever need to restart a db for any reason there is a high chance this change would get lost and it isn't clear to anyone in the future *why* it was ever done